# Вывод данных из БД

Tags: php

Я вывожу данные из БД следующим способом:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = '.$uid.'');
while ( $users = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    echo = ''.$users['first_name'].'';
}
```

Использовать переменную `$users['first_name']` я могу только внутри `while {}`

А как сделать так, чтобы можно было использовать в любой части страницы, написав

```
<?=$users["first_name"]?>
```

p.s.: да, нуб

p.p.s.: ответить желательно развёрнуто

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

Инициализируйте (создайте/подготовьте) заранее массив.(вне блока while).

Затем заполните этот массив данными из вашей выборки.(внутри блока while).

Вот и получиля глобальный массив с нужными данными.

Comment: А можно с конкретным примером?

Comment: Конкретно для вашего случая пример
//Инициализируем массив
$array['first_name'] = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '.$uid.''); while ( $users = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) 
{ //Заполняем массив $array['first_name']
  $array['first_name'][] = $users['first_name']; 
}

получился массив $array['first_name'], который содержит значения поля first_name из каждой строки выборки

Comment: Пробую вывести значение <?=$array['first_name']?> -- выводит "Array"

Comment: Все верно, это же массив данных.

я показал пример, когда выбираться будет много значений из базы и заполняться в массив.

<?=$array['first_name'][0]?> - (вот что надо выводить) первый элемент массива (в вашем случае массив будет содержать только один эелемент)

Comment: Хорошо.
А можно ли выводить значение, например <?=$array['status']?>, предварительно не приравнивая
> $array['status'][] = $users['status'];

Ведь если нужно каждый раз приравнивать -- я могу внутри while {} приравнять к простым переменным, например:

> $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = '.$uid.'');
while ( $users = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
 $u_fname = ''.$users['first_name'].'';
 $u_lname = ''.$users['last_name'].'';
 $u_photo_200 = ''.$users['photo_200'].'';
 $u_verify = ''.$users['verify'].'';
}

Comment: Если результат выборки, одна строка, тогда можете приравнивать к простым переменным.

Но если результат выборке больше одной строки, то нужен массив.

Comment: Если хотите выводить в одной переменной - то так 
<br>
while ( $users = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
  $u_fname .= $users['first_name'].'';
  $u_lname .= $users['last_name'].'';
  $u_photo_200 .= $users['photo_200'].'';
  $u_verify .= $users['verify'].'';
}

Соответственно, каждая переменная будет содержать весь массив данных в 1й строке. Если нужно использовать <?=$array['first_name'][0]?>, то примерно так -  <?=implode('',$array['first_name'][0]);?>